# AVFoundation Camera failing after NavigationLink swift/swiftui

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, camera, avfoundation

Hi I have code for writing to the camera in Swift and SwiftUI. I'm making use of the following resource for the camera and integrated with my SwiftUI view. https://betterprogramming.pub/effortless-swiftui-camera-d7a74abde37e

For some reason, when I go to a new view after I capture a photo, and then I go back to the camera with present.wrappedValue.dismiss(), this following piece of code gets triggered from CameraService.swift:

```
let videoDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoDevice)

 if session.canAddInput(videoDeviceInput) {
                session.addInput(videoDeviceInput)
                self.videoDeviceInput = videoDeviceInput
                
            } else {
                print("Couldn't add video device input to the session.")
                setupResult = .configurationFailed
                session.commitConfiguration()
                return
            }
```

and it outputs that Couldn't add video device input to the session.

Please let me know what could be this issue because it seems to be that Navigation Link is the problem as I can go around from another view to the camera view and it works fine. However, if I dismiss from my navigated view using navigation link, the code for the camera breaks.

Minimal reproducible example by modifying CameraView.swift code from the above link, as well as the GitHub repo to the link:
https://github.com/rorodriguez116/SwiftCamera

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import AVFoundation

final class CameraModel: ObservableObject {
    private let service = CameraService()
    
    @Published var photo: Photo!
    
    @Published var showAlertError = false
    
    @Published var isFlashOn = false
    
    @Published var willCapturePhoto = false
    
    var alertError: AlertError!
    
    var session: AVCaptureSession
    
    private var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init() {
        self.session = service.session
        
        service.$photo.sink { [weak self] (photo) in
            guard let pic = photo else { return }
            self?.photo = pic
        }
        .store(in: &self.subscriptions)
        
        service.$shouldShowAlertView.sink { [weak self] (val) in
            self?.alertError = self?.service.alertError
            self?.showAlertError = val
        }
        .store(in: &self.subscriptions)
        
        service.$flashMode.sink { [weak self] (mode) in
            self?.isFlashOn = mode == .on
        }
        .store(in: &self.subscriptions)
        
        service.$willCapturePhoto.sink { [weak self] (val) in
            self?.willCapturePhoto = val
        }
        .store(in: &self.subscriptions)
    }
    
    func configure() {
        service.checkForPermissions()
        service.configure()
    }
    
    func capturePhoto() {
        service.capturePhoto()
    }
    
    func flipCamera() {
        service.changeCamera()
    }
    
    func zoom(with factor: CGFloat) {
        service.set(zoom: factor)
    }
    
    func switchFlash() {
        service.flashMode = service.flashMode == .on ? .off : .on
    }
}

struct CameraView: View {
    @StateObject var model = CameraModel()
    
    @State var currentZoomFactor: CGFloat = 1.0
    
    @State var showNewPost: Bool = false

    var captureButton: some View {
        Button(action: {

            model.capturePhoto()
            
        }, label: {
            Circle()
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .frame(width: 80, height: 80, alignment: .center)
                .overlay(
                    Circle()
                        .stroke(Color.black.opacity(0.8), lineWidth: 2)
                        .frame(width: 65, height: 65, alignment: .center)
                )
        })
    }
    
    var capturedPhotoThumbnail: some View {
            Group {
                
                if model.photo != nil {

                        Image(uiImage: model.photo.image!)
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                            .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10, style: .continuous))
                            .animation(.spring())
                            .onAppear{
                                self.showNewPost.toggle()
                                print("show new post is \(self.showNewPost)")
                        
                   
                            }
                    
                    
                } else {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                        .frame(width: 60, height: 60, alignment: .center)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                }
            }
            
        
       
    }
    
    var flipCameraButton: some View {
        Button(action: {
            model.flipCamera()
        }, label: {
            Circle()
                .foregroundColor(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
                .frame(width: 45, height: 45, alignment: .center)
                .overlay(
                    Image(systemName: "camera.rotate.fill")
                        .foregroundColor(.white))
        })
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { reader in
            NavigationView {
                ZStack {
                    Color.black.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    
                    VStack {
                        Button(action: {
                            model.switchFlash()
                        }, label: {
                            Image(systemName: model.isFlashOn ? "bolt.fill" : "bolt.slash.fill")
                                .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .medium, design: .default))
                        })
                        .accentColor(model.isFlashOn ? .yellow : .white)
                        
                        CameraPreview(session: model.session)
                            .gesture(
                                DragGesture().onChanged({ (val) in
                                    //  Only accept vertical drag
                                    if abs(val.translation.height) > abs(val.translation.width) {
                                        //  Get the percentage of vertical screen space covered by drag
                                        let percentage: CGFloat = -(val.translation.height / reader.size.height)
                                        //  Calculate new zoom factor
                                        let calc = currentZoomFactor + percentage
                                        //  Limit zoom factor to a maximum of 5x and a minimum of 1x
                                        let zoomFactor: CGFloat = min(max(calc, 1), 5)
                                        //  Store the newly calculated zoom factor
                                        currentZoomFactor = zoomFactor
                                        //  Sets the zoom factor to the capture device session
                                        model.zoom(with: zoomFactor)
                                    }
                                })
                            )
                            .onAppear {
                                model.configure()
                            }
                            .alert(isPresented: $model.showAlertError, content: {
                                Alert(title: Text(model.alertError.title), message: Text(model.alertError.message), dismissButton: .default(Text(model.alertError.primaryButtonTitle), action: {
                                    model.alertError.primaryAction?()
                                }))
                            })
                            .overlay(
                                Group {
                                    if model.willCapturePhoto {
                                        Color.black
                                    }
                                }
                            )
                            .animation(.easeInOut)
                        
                        
                        HStack {
                            capturedPhotoThumbnail
                            
                            Spacer()
                            
                            captureButton
                            
                            Spacer()
                            
                            flipCameraButton
                            
                        }
                        .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                        
                       
                    }
                    
                    
                    NavigationLink(destination: NewPost(), isActive: $showNewPost) {

                    }
                       
                }
            }

        }
    }
}



struct NewPost: View {
  
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var present

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            print("tapped button")
            present.wrappedValue.dismiss() //triggers the configuration failed

        }, label: {
            Text("new post").foregroundColor(Color.black)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include a [mre]?

Comment: just added my modified camera view.swift

Comment: I'm trying to go to the NewPost() after capturing a photo which works on the first session but after I dismiss from NewPost() and go back to CameraView(), it says that session is unable to add the video device input, and get this message:                 print("Couldn't add video device input to the session.")

Comment: I'm pretty confident its due to the navigation link as I can switch and go to different views outside of NewPost() and come back to CameraView() and then it works but when I directly dismiss, it fails

Comment: No one can compile the code that you've included -- it relies on a ton of custom types that are omitted from you code. With a [mre], you have a much better chance of getting an answer.

Comment: I can link a GitHub repo of the minimal reproducible example but since this combines swift,swiftui, and avfoundation from a third party resource, I'm not sure how to link all the code to reproduce the problem here

Comment: Are `CropViewCroppingStyle`, `UserViewModel`, `RegisterViewModel`, etc *all* necessary to recreate this issue? Minimal means that you cut out what isn't necessary to recreate the issue.

Comment: Sorry, just updated the code with all the necessary components for CameraView()

Comment: Would you like the code for NewPost() as well, it simply shows the photo passed in, and triggers present.wrappedValue.dismiss() on a cancel button press

Comment: A minimal, reproducible example can basically be copied and pasted and expected to represent the problem. Do what is necessary to make that happen.

Comment: Just updated my code to get the minimal reproducible example with the navigation link and the wrapped dismiss